# can I run version 16 and 12 of sybase on same machine?

Tags: database, sybase

Currently I am running sybase version 16 and now I want to install version 12 too. But I am getting error 1500 (The invalid tolerance.).which I don't understand.

Comment: We need a lot more information to make this answerable.  Sybase was a company, not a database so you need to specify which sybase product you are reffering to.  Also, you need to tell us what platform you are installing your software on, and as much detail as you can find.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about Sybase ASE (which you didn't specify), yes you can. I am running ASE 11.x, 12.x, 15.x and 16.x all on the same Linux box, at the same time.
On Linux/Unix, it's easy, but you have to run each server in its own environment (i.e. set the environment variables correctly before starting the server. 
On Windows, it's also easy when you run the server in the foreground in a DOS box (with the right env.var settings). 
But when running ASE servers as a Windows Service, this gets very difficult: in essence you can have only one set of environment variables for the services. Workarounds exist but these are very clumsy and require constant maintenance when performing upgrades of ASE -- so I would not recommend using multiple ASE versions on Windows when one of these ASE servers runs as a service.